# Why am I getting an odd pattern from my image sensor?

Tags: analog, capacitance, image-sensor

I am using an Omnivision [OV7251](https://www.ovt.com/sensors/OV7251) image sensor with 640x480 greyscale pixels. Currently, it's not properly attached to its lens, so I'm seeing mostly grey. This is the image I'm getting back from it:

[image: Strange pattern from image sensor]

Not hugely surprising on first glance, but when we look closer, we can see that the top 50 rows look fine, a little noisy. Here is a zoomed in portion of the image from near the top. I've brightened it up so you can see the details.

[image: Slightly noisy image]

But further down the image, a pattern begins to emerge (again I have brightened it to bring out the details):

[image: Strange pattern from image sensor]

The bottom right pixel from every 2x2 group is a little darker.

What is going on here? What can be causing this pattern? My only thought is that it might be an electrical issue. Perhaps there isn't enough capacitance for the analog power pin on the sensor, and as it samples the pixels, it's starting to suffer some voltage droop. And perhaps the pattern comes from the way the pixels are sampled according to the [Bayer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter).

Has anyone experienced this before, and knows what to do to solve it?

---

**Update:**

I have tried increasing the capacitance on the analog input pin, and it made no difference to the pattern.

Comment: It does look like it could be the Bayer pattern. Can you double-check the part number if it really is the grayscale version?

Comment: Interesting idea. But I suspect that's not the problem, because this effect is not seen in the top portion of the image.

Comment: adjust the light level and try again

Comment: @Jasen - Do you mean I should adjust the amount of light in the scene, or adjust the exposure / gain of the sensor?  I have tried adjusting the scene light level, and it seems I need some level of grey to see this pattern. If I make it completely dark, or completely overexposed, then I don't see the pattern, because every pixel is either 0x00 or 0xFF respectively.

Comment: @Justme - I have just tried illuminating the sensor with Reg, Green and Blue light separately, and it makes no difference. It's clearly not an RGB image sensor, and the same pattern appears, and it's always in the lower 7/8 of the image.

Comment: OK - have you configured it properly, giving it a proper clock, and do the serrings match how the MIPI receiver expects the data?

Comment: @Justme - I believe I have. The schematic is exactly according to the datasheet, and the layout is good in my opinion. The clock is delivered from a local, accurate oscillator. Presumably, if the clock wasn't present, or the chip wasn't configured properly, I wouldn't get any picture at all.